# Sorting of IEnumerable<T> in MVC 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

My Service layer returns a `IEnumerable<ResortsView>` to my Controller and I have to provide an option to SORT the results on UI by following criteria: Price (Excluding ZERO Price Items), SupplierName & Rating. Here is the code snippet of my objects/classes:

```
[Serializable]
public class ResortsView : SupplierView
{
    public IList<ProductView> ResortProducts { get; set; }
    public string CheckInTime { get; set; }
    public string CheckOutTime { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<ImageView> Images { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class SupplierView
{
    public string SupplierID { get; set; }
    public string SupplierName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Rating { get; set; } 
    public string URL { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class ProductView
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal? Price { get; set; }
    public ErrorView PricingError { get; set; }
}
```

What is the best way to handle sorting of results inside `IEnumerable<ResortsView>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `OrderBy` method of the LINQ stack:

```
IEnumerable<ResortsView> source = GetResorts();
var model = source.OrderBy(rv => rv.CheckInTime);
```

To order by the lowest, non-zero price in `ResortProducts`:

```
var model = source.OrderBy(rv => rv.ResortProducts.Where(p => p.Price > 0).Min(p => p.Price));
```

Comment: Thanks Femaref. That would work for properties inside ResortsView. How can I Do OrderBy on Price which is inside ProductView?

Comment: Do you mean an `IEnumerable<ProductView>`?

Comment: Nope. `ResortsView` contains `public IList<ProductView> ResortProducts { get; set; }` and `ProductView` has Price. So How can I Sort on Price? `source.OrderBy(rv => rv.ResortProducts.Price)` won't work.

Comment: What do you want to sort by? The average of the prices? the max? the min?

Comment: `IEnumerable<ResortsView>` would contain list of resorts. Each resort could contain multiple products with their pricing. User can sort the resorts by the product prices (ascending & descending) excluding ignoring priced items.

Comment: I'm certainly aware of that. You want to sort the `IList<ProductView>` **in** the single elements of the `IEnumerable<ResortsView>`?

Comment: I want to sort `IList<ProductView>` ascending or descending for ALL elements of `IEnumerable<ResortsView>`

Comment: In fact when I loop thru `IEnumerable<ResortsView>` to display list of Resorts on UI I have to display LOWEST NON-ZERO price for each resort as the starting price. So basically I have to grab lowest price from `IList<ProductView>` for each resort.

Comment: Thx Femaref. I am getting following exception "at least one object must implement icomparable.". Do I need to implement IComarable?

Comment: Sorry, there was a lambda missing in the `Min` operator.

Comment: Femaref, How can I replace/edit ResortProducts `(IList<ProductView>)` for a particular supplier inside `IEnumerable<ResortsView>` using SupplierID as key? Basically based on some user action, I have to refresh list of products for a particular supplier which I will retrieve using AJAX.

Comment: Under the assumption of `SupplierID` being unique, you can get the associated `ResortView` using `source.Single(r => r.SupplierID == input)`. You really should read a tutorial about linq, also have a look at [101 linq samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746). A suitable starting point would be this [overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb308959.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Most likely if you'll want to use the Dynamic LINQ library, [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) are some instructions and a download link.

You'll need to have your action accept some sorting parameters:

```
public ActionResult MyAction(string sortField)
{
    return View(myService.MyData().OrderBy(sortField));
}
```